# Trying to save value from ajax/jquery submit form in database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have CSS Pie chart which when I click on one of the pies, it opens a simple submit form.

The problem is that when I click submit button nothing goes into the database. Just shows thank you message and this is it. Nothing in the console.

I have put the pie chart front part here: https://jsfiddle.net/096hgmqd/. When you click on Button 1 it opens the form below.

Here is the jquery/ajax part

```
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://res.cloudinary.com/positionrelativ/raw/upload/v1492377595/jquery.rwdImageMaps_lq5sye.js'></script>
<script  src="script.js"></script>
<script>
// validate form on keyup and submit

var formData = new FormData(form);
    
$("#loadingmessage").show();
$.ajax({
        url: "submit.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        success: function(data) {
            if(data == 'success') {
                $("#loadingmessage").hide();
                $("#sucessmsg").show();
            }
            if(data == 'error') {
                $("#loadingmessage").hide();
                $("#errormsg").show();
            }
        },
        error: function(){}             
});     
</script>
```

And the PHP part - `submit.php`

```
$connect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=MYDBNAME", "DBUSERNAME", "DBPASSWORD");
$message = '';
if(isset($_POST["saveAnswers"])) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO clarity (name) VALUES (:name)";
     
    $user_data = array( ':name'  => $_POST["name"] ); 

    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);

    if($statement->execute($user_data)) {
        $message = '<div class="alert alert-success"> Registration Completed Successfully </div>';
    } else {
        $message = '<div class="alert alert-success"> There is an error in Registration</div>';
    }
}
```

Can anyone help here?

UPDATE: current code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('form').on('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
                url: "submit.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: formData,
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData:false,
                success: function(data) {
                    if(data.result == 'success') {
                         $("#loadingmessage").hide();
                         $("#sucessmsg").show();
                    } else if(data.result == 'error') {
                         $("#loadingmessage").hide();
                         $("#errormsg").show();
                    }
                },
                error: function(){}             
        });
    }); 
});
```

And PHP

```
if(isset($_POST["saveAnswers"]))
{
    sleep(5);
    $query = "INSERT INTO clarity (name) VALUES (:name)";
     
    $user_data = array(
      ':name'  => $_POST["name"]
    ); 
    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
    $response = 'error';
       if($statement->execute($user_data)) {
         $response = 'success';
       }
       echo json_encode(array('result' => $response));
    }
```

HTML form

```
  <form class="form-wrapper" action="" method="post" id="submitForm1">
    <fieldset class="section is-active">
      <h3>What is your name?</h3>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your Name">
      <button type="submit" class="button" name="saveAnswers" id="saveAnswers">Submit</button>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
```

Comment: Your comment in the JS code says `// validate form on keyup and submit` but I don't see any code to actually handle the submit event...it looks like this AJAX code will be run as soon as your page loads, which is no good. Also your PHP code doesn't appear to output any status for the AJAX to decide what do show when it gets the response

Comment: Okay, that's something.

Comment: Your PHP does not return anything. You just saved the output to a variable named `$message`.

Comment: True. It was while tested. Changed with `echo` on the code

Comment: @Goro will need to be more than that - your JS (in `if(data == 'success')`) looks for the simple word "success" in the output, but if you're echoing your  `$message` var, it contains complex HTML. These two things will not match, obviously.

Comment: @Goro that's incorrect. Changing to `echo` does not help.

Answer (score 1):

you need to submit your form.Your ajax request will fire as soon as the page loads not on form submit.

```
$('form').on('submit',function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
        url: "submit.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        success: function(data) {
            if(data == 'success') {
                $("#loadingmessage").hide();
                $("#sucessmsg").show();
            }
            if(data == 'error') {
                $("#loadingmessage").hide();
                $("#errormsg").show();
            }
        },
        error: function(){}             
});
});
```

Comment: Thanks but still doesn't save up the name to the DB. Can't see the submit also on the console of the browser.

Comment: @Goro to see an AJAX request you need to look in the Network tool normally, not the console (unless you write something specifically in the JS code to log to the console e.g. when the submit event fires, and/or when a response is received from AJAX)

Comment: On the Network tab I see just the documents that are loaded during the page load. Nothing shows up after the submit button is clicked.

Comment: can you post your form code

Comment: @Goro make sure you put this JS code either a) after the HTML of the form, or b) inside a document.ready block, to ensure the form element exists at the time it tries to bind the event to it. If the form HTML is loaded dynamically after the initial page load though, that's another story again.

Comment: @ADyson, I have wrapped it in document ready block and it is after the HTML of the form.

Answer (score 1):

For the DB problem, you first need to fix the communication between PHP and JS. Also, you can debug the data with `console.log(form)` in JS. You can also debug at the server-side, you can return the debugging data, especially the `$_POST` like this:

```
$debug = var_export($_POST, true);
echo json_encode(array('debug' => $debug);
```

And you can view the response in the Developer Console of your browser, to see whether the information is received by the PHP or not.

---

Your PHP does not return anything. You just saved the output to a variable named `$message`. In your jQuery AJAX call, you expect there are some data returned, either `success` or `error`, but your PHP script does not provide these.

Try to change the PHP if-else clause to:

```
$response = 'error';
if($statement->execute($user_data)) {
    $response = 'success';
}
echo json_encode(array('result' => $response));
```

and add the following line to the very first line of PHP:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Last, in your jQuery call, change the if-else clause in the `success` handler to:

```
if(data.result == 'success') {
     $("#loadingmessage").hide();
     $("#sucessmsg").show();
} else if(data.result == 'error') {
     $("#loadingmessage").hide();
     $("#errormsg").show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Now I get an error at least after submit button is clicked: `Uncaught ReferenceError: formData is not defined`

Comment: Do you have the line something like `const form = document.getElementById('form');` before the `FormData()` line? Assuming your `<form>` tag has an `id` attribute named `form`. See [examples here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData)

Comment: No, I don't. The form has an `id` called `submitForm1` ( I have updated my question with the form ). And I've changed the form tag in the JS part with `submitForm1` and now I don't get this error anymore.

Comment: Still, you need this line: `const form = document.getElementById('submitForm1');` before the `formData` line.

Comment: I have added it on the next line after the `$( document ).ready(function() {`. The change is that don't have error anymore and still nothing shown on either tabs - Network or Console.

Comment: do you see your post url in network tab??

Comment: @steveyout, nope, didn't see anything in the network tab nor in the Console tab

Comment: If you see nothing changed in the Network tab when you submit the form (i.e. press the submit button), it means that the on submit action is not triggered. You can prove it by adding the following line before the `e.preventDefault();`: `console.log('on submit triggered');`

Comment: @Raptor, yes, I do see `console.log('on submit triggered');` in the console tab. So the problem is between ajax and php part.

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned that you don't see anything on the Network tab. This means that there is "no connection" between your Ajax/jQuery and PHP parts and I believe that the actual problem is in your Ajax part. You can try like this. (I have tested it and it works just fine).

HTML part

```
<p id="show_message" style="display: none">Form data sent.</p>
<span id="error" style="display: none"></span>

<form class="form-wrapper" action="" method="post" id="submitForm1">
   <fieldset class="section is-active">
      <h3>What is your name?</h3>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your Name">
      <button type="submit" class="button" name="saveAnswers" id="saveAnswers">Submit</button>
   </fieldset>
</form>
```

Ajax part

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function($){
    // hide messages 
    $("#error").hide();
    $("#show_message").hide();
    // on submit...
    $('#submitForm1').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#error").hide();
        // if name is required
        var name = $("input#name").val();
        if(name == ""){
            $("#error").fadeIn().text("Name required.");
            $("input#name").focus();
            return false;
        }
        // ajax
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: "submit.php",
            data: $(this).serialize(), // get all form field value in serialize form
            success: function(){
            $("#show_message").fadeIn();
            }
        });
    });  
    return false;
});
</script>
```